# ALOS Palsar SLC data products for geological mapping

Tags: geology, structural-geology, data-analysis

I have some ALOS palsar SLC data products which are downloaded from ESA database and they are processed with ESA ALOS-PALSAR IPF processor which is different from JAXA. Formerly it was not possible to load these datatype to SNAP but newly after some updates SNAP is useful to load and use the mentioned data. 
The main question is that "How can I use ALOS PALSAR SLC data for geologic mapping based on the difference of geologic units to RADAR waves and different backscatters?".
Any Idea to combine spectral data (ie.ETM and ASTER) and SAR data to improve the geological mapping process?